# Uploading files to service account in Google Drive

Tags: file-upload, google-drive-api, service-accounts

We have a requirement where we should provide capability to upload files up to 100 GB size. Current flow which we have is to put the file from client location/local system to the application server. Then application server pushes the file to a service account in Google Drive server. I would like to know if there is a way to push the file from local system directly to service account in Google Drive. This would help us to not have to store such big files in application server. Please let me know. Also would like to know if we can actually have Drive installed in our local system to point to a service account. This way these big files can be put into the drive location and it will be synced to server in the background.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know if there is a way to push the file from local system directly to service account in Google Drive

The only way I know is for you to upload them. The [Upload Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) page in the Drive API documentation details this feature. In your case, you'll have to use `uploadType=resumable` due to the file size you'll upload.

> Also would like to know if we can actually have Drive installed in our local system to point to a service account

Syncing ala-Dropbox might be a bit tricky, I haven't read anything in the Drive documentation that has this feature. Syncing to desktop is usually just a `.glink` [shortcut](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk#use_shortcuts) that will open up a browser.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem with that approach is that the code for upload has to be written and deployed to application server. When we load the file in application server, the file will get uploaded to the tmp directory in application server and then pushed to Google Drive. We do not want such big files to go to appserver at all. That's why wanted to know if we can push the files directly to Drive. An FTP or a file sync mechanism which puts the files to a service account would be ideal solutions.